# com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I Try to create dash format for video with help of MP4Box 
When i run command :- 
`MP4Box -dash 2000 -rap -frag-rap -profile onDemand 1OaG8xKJPZg-320.mp4 1OaG8xKJPZg-720.mp4` 
it show some warning[using Ubuntu 16.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7GLn.png)  
then after i received 1OaG8xKJPZg-320_dash.mpd 1OaG8xKJPZg-320_dashinit.mp4
1OaG8xKJPZg-720_dashinit.mp4 these file i uploaded in google cloud with publically share link , for Reference i uploaded in google drive with my player activity

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t_YF_TJrMnQOQ8BNBiDjC8erPhRjVy_1?usp=sharing
```

when i run my program i received error [exoplayer2.ParserException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqeJd.png)

```
Source error.
                                                                               com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: inputStream does not contain a valid media presentation description
                                                                                   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:96)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:54)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:115)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

i try multiple time but every time i received same error

Comment: see cause of the exception https://github.com/3sidedcube/Android-ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/dash/mpd/MediaPresentationDescriptionParser.java#L90

Comment: @Redman Thanks for comment i changed my video format and code now its not dash format but its working fine