# Open SMIL format in Android TV player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, android-tv, smil

I am working on an Android TV prototype where I need to render videos from a backend which is returning the content url as `SMIL` format.

I have followed the codelab tutorial for [exoplayer here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0)

When I change the media source to a SMIL format url, I am getting an exception as

`com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: inputStream does not contain a valid media presentation description`

I have also referred to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781908/how-to-use-smil-file-in-android-development), but it's not the solution for exoplayer.

Comment: Maybe you want to check [this line](https://github.com/3sidedcube/Android-ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/dash/mpd/MediaPresentationDescriptionParser.java#L90) of your code? Also, have you checked [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568325/com-google-android-exoplayer2-parserexception)?